# Wordpress password protected posts generate error 403

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, post, passwords, protected

I password protected a Wordpress post. When I enter the right password for the post, I  get a 403 error instead of getting access to my post content. When typing a wrong password, I also get that 403 error.

This is what the .htaccess (at the root of the website) looks like:
(not sure how relevant this is)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

#Redirections
RedirectPermanent /qr   http://www.myaddress.com
```

edit 16/04/13:
It has been suggested that it may be a hosting configuration problem. But where to look for it? What should be tested?
On another website tested (on the same host) I get a 'Forbidden' result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting my host, turns out it was really a configuration problem on their side. If you have a similar problem it may be worth checking out with your host provider.